# How to change boot animation timing of android phone?

Tags: android

I have rooted my Android smart phone and I want to change boot animation. I changed the zip file and new boot animation works fine but the problem comes to duration. The boot animation animates twice and then it comes to main screen. I want to animate it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply unzip the boot animation. you will find a file with `.txt` extension. Open it and change the FPS (frames per sec) and you will be able to increase or decrease the boot animation duration.